# C++ class with same members with different types

Tags: c++

Is it possible to generate automatically something like this? I want specific members only once and generate three classes (they are similar but...)

```
class recipe{
public:
  int timeToPrepare;
  std::string name;
}

class recipeQuery{
public:
  baseQuery<int> timeToPrepare;
  baseQuery<std::string> name;
}


class recipeScheme{
public:
  schemeItem<int> timeToPrepare;
  schemeItem<std::string> name;
}
```

Comment: Generate how? In what context do you envision the need to generate code? As a pre-compilation step? Do you want C++ code, or do you want a script or tool that generates code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<template<typename> class T>
class recipe{
public:
    T<int> timeToPrepare;
    T<std::string> name;
};

typedef recipe<baseQuery> recipeQuery;
typedef recipe<schemeItem> recipeScheme;
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
template <class T1 = int, class T2 = std::string> class recipe {
    T1 timeToPrepare;
    T2 name;
};

typedef recipe< baseQuery<int>, baseQuery<std::string> > recipeQuery;

typedef recipe< schemeItem<int>, schemeItem<std::string> > recipeQuery;
```